# Symfony2 doctrine add a virtual field to entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have an `account(account_id, value, ...)` entity and use it in several controllers. Just for one case I need to provide additional information, `account(account_id, value, correct_value, ...)`. 
My DQL Query gives me 2 accunts but I need to get the correct value from correct account in to the account as virtual field or so.

```
SELECT account, correctAccount FROM ... JOIN ...
```

The DQL query works fine. But I get the accounts like this:

```
[account1, correctAccount1, account2, correctAccount2, ... ]
```

But I need them like this:

```
[account1(...value, correct_value,...), account2(...value, correct_value,...)... ]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: sounds like a perfect task for custom repositories, write a custom repository function for your 'one case', retrieve the data as you can get it, transform it following your desired outcome and return it - voila.